# Racket Scheme - if else statements

Tags: scheme, racket

Currently using racket, can't find much help, was wondering if someone can help me..

I  have

```
(define (reciprocal x) (/ 1 x))
```

however, having a 0 as an ex shouldn't work.
So I tried modifying it to

```
(define (reciprocal x) (if (= x 0)((#f)(/ 1 x)))
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I was hoping that it would return false if x = 0 but it does not do this. I can still get the reciprocal, just doesn't check for the x. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My code signals the error "application: not a procedure" or "call to non procedure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064955/my-code-signals-the-error-application-not-a-procedure-or-call-to-non-procedu)

Answer (score 3):

You need to restructure the if-else clause. Typical Scheme syntax for this form is as follows:

```
(if (predicate expression) then else)
```

So you would rewrite your code as follows:

```
(define (reciprocal x) (if (= x 0) #f (/ 1 x)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I see what I did wrong. Much appreciated

Comment: You might see people use `and`, for instance `(and (not (zero? x)) (/ 1 x))`.