# Scheme multiple procedures in cond

Tags: scheme, lisp

In one case of my `cond`, I need to do multiple procedures then return a value at the end. However, my current implementation gives me an error:

`application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments`

```
(cond
    [(string? expr) expr]
    [(number? expr) expr]
    [(list? expr) (begin 
        (hash-set! my-table (car expr) (cdr expr))
        ("hi")  ; I want to return this
    )
    ]
)
```

Can anybody help me understand how I'd have multiple lines in a `cond`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My code signals the error "application: not a procedure" or "call to non procedure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064955/my-code-signals-the-error-application-not-a-procedure-or-call-to-non-procedu). Look at the "wrapping variables" part though you are wrapping literals.

Answer (score 2):

It's not multiple lines in the cond that's your problem, it's the ("hi").  You're trying to call "hi" as a procedure by putting it in the parens and "hi" is a string, not a procedure.

In fact, you don't need the (begin ...) form to have multiple lines in there.  Just put the lines you want after the test.