# Using racket to return the list of animal's name corresponding to the given animal list

Tags: racket

I'm now using racket to build the function that return the list of animal's name corresponding to the given animal list.
But there comes a problem.

```
(define (name-pets l)
    (cond
        [(eq? "dog" first(l)) (append 'happy (name-pets (rest (l))))]
        [(eq? "cat" first(l)) (append 'smart (name-pets (rest (l))))]
        [(eq? "pig" first(l)) (append 'pinky (name-pets (rest (l))))]
        [else (append 'unnamed (name-pets (rest (l))))]))
(name-pets (list "pig" "cat" "dog" "dolphin"))
```

And when I ran the code,

> application: not a procedure;  expected a procedure that can be
>   applied to arguments
>   given: '("pig" "cat" "dog" "dolphin")
>   arguments...: [none]

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My code signals the error "application: not a procedure" or "call to non procedure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064955/my-code-signals-the-error-application-not-a-procedure-or-call-to-non-procedu)

Answer (score 0):

Change `first(l)` to `(first l)` and `(rest (l))` to `(rest l)`.
Note that you can't insert extra parentheses in Racket.
The syntax `(l)` means call `l`, but since `l` is a list and not a function, 
you run into problems.