# scheme define list as local variable

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, max, racket, fold

My target is do define list as local variable in order to get max element from it. My code:

```
#lang racket
(define (f a b c)
    (list (+ (* a a) (* b b) (* c c)) (+ a c))
    (define (max-of-list-2 lst)
      (foldr max (first lst) (rest lst)))
  (max max_from_list 12))
(f 5 6 7)
```

In second row I have defined list with calculated falues. My target is to pass it to next row in order to get max number from it, and finaly to get max from max of list and 12. What I do wrong. How to handle it?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Lexical-Binding.html

Comment: name it with another define: `(define lst (list ...))`. then you can refer to it by name in any lisp expression, like e.g. a function call.

Comment: but I cannot call (max max-of-list-2 (lst) 12)

Comment: @IntoTheDeep what about `(max (max-of-list-2 lst) 12)`? @IntoTheDeep

Comment: @WillNess please add this as an answer

Comment: @IntoTheDeep  It's difficult for us to take your non-working code and work out your actual intentions. Can you please describe the problem better? Can you think of a better name than `f`? What is the return value supposed to be? What is the point of the `(* a a)` `(* b b)` `(* c c)` and `(+ a c)` values? Is this just an assignment?

Comment: For `(max max-of-list-2 (lst) 12)` to work `lst` cannot be a list, but a procedure. You'll get [application: not a procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064955/my-code-signals-the-error-application-not-a-procedure-or-call-to-non-procedu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *several* `define`s at the top of your function.

So you meant

```
(define (f a b c)
  (define lst (list (+ (* a a) (* b b) (* c c)) 
                    (+ a c)))
  (define (max-of-list-2 lst)
      (foldr max (first lst) (rest lst)))
  (max (max-of-list-2 lst) 12))
```

but that's just equivalent to

```
(define (f a b c)
  (foldr max 12 (list (+ (* a a) (* b b) (* c c)) 
                      (+ a c))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an inner define, like this:

```
(define (f a b c)
    (define max_from_list (list (+ (* a a) (* b b) (* c c)) (+ a c)))
    (define (max-of-list-2 lst)
      (foldr max (first lst) (rest lst)))
  (max max_from_list 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat difficult to work out your intentions, but this is the best understanding I can come up with -

```
(define (max a b)
  (if (< a b)
      b
      a))

(define (f a . more)
  (if (empty? more)
      (max a 12)
      (max a (apply f more))))

(f 5 6 7)
; => 12

(f 5 20 30)
; => 30
```