# Why am i getting this error when calling a function in a function?

Tags: syntax, common-lisp

I am calling a simple function i wrote in another function but getting an unexpected error.

I have saved and executed the first equation 'square-x' and then called it in the second fucntion 'sum-of-squares' in a different file.

First function:

```
(defun square-x (x)
  "gives the square of a number"
  (* x x))
```

Second function:

```
(defun sum-of-squares (a b)
  "sums the squares of two values"
  ((+ (square-x a) 
      (square-x b))))
```

When trying to execute this function the error messages are 'the variable a is defined but never used' and the same for b. But i have used them in the calling of another function. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the form `(+ (square-x a) (square-x b))` with no arguments. In CL only symbols and lambda forms may be in operator position, not `(+ (square-x a) (square-x b))`

```
;; wrong
((+ (square-x a) (square-x b)))

;; correct 
(+ (square-x a) (square-x b))
```

In Both CLISP an SBCL this is the main ERROR, but I notice SBCL also mentions as a warning that `a` and `b` are never used. This is of course because it disregards the code in the wrong operator `(+ (square-x a) (square-x b))` completely.

In Scheme, where expressions in operator position is allowed, you would have got [Application: not a procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48064955/1565698) because the result of `(+ (square-x a) (square-x b))`, which most likely would be a number, would be called with no arguments as a function.