# Scheme - Beginner Syntax Issues with greater than, less than, and an and condition

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm just starting to write in scheme in DrRacket. However, like we all probably know, those small changes in syntax always mess us up!

I believe my error is in the and conditional. If someone could take a look and tell me what's wrong that would be great!

```
; in-range?: int int list of numbers --> boolean
(define in-range?
  (lambda (a b s)
    (cond [(null? s) #t] ;List is empty
          [(null? a) #f]
          [(null? b) #f]
          [((and >= (car s)) ((a) <= (car s)) (b)) (in-range? (a) (b) (cdr s))]
          [else #f]
     )))
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you have `null?` checks on `a` and `b`, because the signature says `a` and `b` are integers, not lists

Comment: To return false if they're empty, I changed it a few minutes ago after realizing the program doesn't even go if they're empty anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine this form:

```
(test a b)
```

You can see it is an application because of the parentheses when `test` is not a syntax operand. Then `test` is evaluated and the expected outcome is a procedure that can be called with the evaluated arguments `a` and `b`.

You have this as the only epression in a cond term:

```
((and >= (car s)) ((a) <= (car s)) (b)) (in-range? (a) (b) (cdr s))
```

This is an application. `(and >= (car s)) ((a) <= (car s)) (b))` is not a syntax operand. Then it is evaluated and the expected outcome is a procedure that takes at least one argument, the evaluation of `(in-range? (a) (b) (cdr s))`.

Since the expression is `and` which is a syntax operand we know it will either be `#f` or `#t` and you should have gotten an error like [`Application: not a procedure`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064955/my-code-signals-the-error-application-not-a-procedure-or-call-to-non-procedu)

Parentheses around something in Scheme is like parentheses after something in algol languages like C# and JavaScript. Imagine this expression:

```
((a.car >=)(), (<= a() s.car)())(in-range(a(), b(), s.cdr))
```

Lots of syntax errors there in JavaScript too :-o