# How to solve an error that comes from defining a variable?

Tags: scheme

```
(define while
      (lambda (rounds)
        (if (> rounds 0) 
            ((define compMove (random 3)) (display compMove))
             (while (- rounds 1))
        )
      )
  )
```

Above is program written in scheme, however I get an error saying that invalid context for definition. This is around (define compMove (random 3)).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not Scheme.

According to [the report](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.2) you are only allowed to have `define` top level and The first expression of the body of a `lambda`, `let`, `let*`, `let-values`, `let*-values`, `letrec`, or `letrec*` expression.

In addition you have wrapped two expressions in parentheses as if that would make a block. It doesn't. What it will try to do is to evaluate the operator and then call the result as a procedure. Since `define` is special it fails. With any other form you would get [Application: not a procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064955/my-code-signals-the-error-application-not-a-procedure-or-call-to-non-procedu).

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but I did that so that the value of compMove changes. I thought that by doing a call function that would work. So how would I have it so each time compMove changes?

Comment: @JosephMenezes It is a useless binding since you can just have the expression that creates the value as the argument to `display`: `(display (random 3))`. If you want a local binding you should be looking at `let`

Comment: I found that the issue was actually a bug in my IDE, but thank you for the suggestion, as it makes the way my program looks more readable.