# Quicksort in Scheme using a partition

Tags: sorting, scheme, quicksort, partitioning

I have a partition for a quicksort:

```
(define (partition pivot lst)
  ((lambda (s) (s s lst list))
   (lambda (s l* c)
     (if (null? l*)
         (c '() '())
         (let ((x (car l*)))
           (s s (cdr l*)
              (lambda (a b)
                (if (< x pivot)
                    (c (cons x a) b)
                    (c a (cons x b))))))))))
```

[partition code source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72503001/14182413)

Testing:

```
 =>(partition '5 '(1 3 5 7 9 8 6 4 2))
;Value: ((1 3 4 2) (5 7 9 8 6))
```

How can I implement this partition in a quicksort? I've tried this so far:

```
(define (quicksort lst)
  (if (null? lst) '()
    (let* ((y (car lst))
           (pn (partition y (cdr lst))))
      (append (quicksort (car pn))      
              (list y)                  
              (quicksort (cdr pn))))))
```

Comment: That looks like it should work if you change one `cdr` to `cadr`.

Comment: Or `list` to `cons`.

Comment: You should perhaps make your `partition` more readable by using recursion instead of relying on code that looks like it has been done with maximum restrictions. Variable naming can help in readability and I cannot see any logic in calling the pivot `y`.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code is trivially fixed by changing one `cdr` to `cadr`:

```
(define (partition pivot lst)
  ((lambda (s) (s s lst list))
   ......))           ; ^^^^  `list` the top continuation

(define (quicksort lst)
  (if (null? lst) '()
    (let* ((y (car lst))
           (pn (partition y (cdr lst))))
      (append 
        (quicksort (car pn))      
        (list y)                  
        (quicksort (cadr pn))))))
               ;;   ^^^^  cdr --> cadr
```

because the top continuation used in `partition` is `list`, and so the call

```
  (partition pivot lst)
```

is equivalent to the call

```
  (list { x IN lst SUCH THAT x < pivot }
        { x IN lst SUCH THAT x >= pivot } )
```

*(the parts in `{...}` are pseudocode, where we don't care about the implementation, just the results)*

And so to access the two parts of that list built by `partition` you need to use `car` and `cadr`.

Or you could keep the `cdr` in the accessing part of your code in `quicksort` if you'd change that top continuation to `cons`:

```
(define (partition pivot lst)
  ((lambda (s) (s s lst cons))
   ......))           ; ^^^^  `cons` the top continuation

(define (quicksort lst)
  (if (null? lst) 
    '()
    (let* ((y (car lst))
           (pn (partition y (cdr lst))))
      (append 
        (quicksort (car pn))      
        (list y)                  
        (quicksort (cdr pn))))))
               ;;   ^^^^  `cdr` works fine with `cons`
```

This because of the ***general principle*** in programming, where the functions used to *build* our data dictate which functions are to be used to *access* that data:

```
    (list   <A>   <B>  )
            car   cadr

    (cons   <A>   <B>  )
            car   cdr
```

( this particular correspondence is because `(list <A> <B>)` is the same as `(cons <A> (cons <B> '()))` and `(cadr <C>)` is the same as `(car (cdr <C>))`: )

```
    (list  <A>         <B>     )
 =
    (cons  <A>   (cons <B> '()))
           car   cdr
                       car
```

And conversely, the functions we use to access our data dictate the implementation of the function which must be used to build that data.

Of course that way of coding in your question is considered unnecessarily convoluted by modern standards since it *emulates* recursion through argument passing and reuse, -- just like in the famous **Y** combinator, -- but any Scheme worthy of its name already supports recursion.

So this `partition` would normally be written as the fully equivalent yet more readable code using the *"named `let`"* construct,

```
(define (partition pivot lst)
  (let s ( (l*   lst)      ; first `l*` is `lst`
           (c    cons) )   ; top   `c`  is `cons`
     (if (null? l*)
         (c '() '())
         (let ((x (car l*)))
           (s (cdr l*)
              (lambda (a b)
                (if (< x pivot)
                    (c  (cons x a)  b)
                    (c  a   (cons x b)))))))))
```

except the name `loop` is conventionally used in place of `s` here (which itself most probably is intended as the shortening of "`self`").

But the true trouble with your quicksort/partition pair is *algorithmic*.

Yes I say pair (in non-`cons` sense of course) since the two go together -- just as with the data access/creation functions which must work together too.

Implementation of one [dictates the implementation of the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8871918/849891) -- in *both* directions, too. `partition`'s code dictates `quicksort`'s, or if we'd written `quicksort` first, we'd need to implement the `partition` in the corresponding way -- so that the two ***work together***. Which means  `quicksort` indeed producing the correct results, turning any input list into a sorted one:

```
(quicksort lst) --->  

      { xs SUCH THAT
             FOR ANY splitting xs = { ..., x, ...ys }
             AND ANY splitting ys = { ..., y, ...   }
             IT HOLDS THAT x <= y
           AND ALSO xs is a permutation of lst 
             (which implies (length lst) == (length xs))
      }
```

So then, what *is* that trouble? It is that *the true* *`quicksort`* does *no* work whatsoever after the partitioning. *None*:

```
(define (quicksort! lst)
  (if (null? lst) 
    '()
    (let* ((y (car lst))
           (pn (partition! y lst)))
      (quicksort! (car pn))         ; no `append`, NB!
      (quicksort! (cdr pn)))))      ; no (list y) either
```

How is that even possible? What kind of `partition!` implementation would make that work? Well, most certainly not a functional one.

Instead it must be changing (i.e. *mutating*) the very `lst` *itself* somehow:

```
     { a, b, c, ....., k, l, m, ..... }
   -->
     { d, e, ....,   p,   n, o, ..... }  
       ~~~~~~~~~~~        ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

where we denote with `p` the partition point -- so that indeed all that's left to do after *this* kind of partitioning ***"in-place"*** is to sort the first part, and then to sort the second part, -- and then there's nothing more left to be done, after that! Which was the key insight in the original Tony Hoare's formulation of it:

```
  TO SORT
     { a, b, c, ....., k, l, m, ..... }  DO:
  PARTITION it into
     { d, e, ....,   p,   n, o, ..... }  AND THEN:
       ~~~~~~~~~~~        ~~~~~~~~~~~
        SORT!               SORT!
                 DONE.
```

This partitioning is usually implemented with `swap!` which actually *swaps* two elements *in the* underlying data structure. Most usually that data structure is an array with its facilities to change the value stored in it at any given index.

But it can also be a list, where the change i.e. *mutation* can be done with the `set-car!` primitive.

Looks like we'd need to build a list of `cdr`s out of the input list, and another one in reverse, -- to be able to iterate over them in both directions, back and forth, -- to make that happen.

I'll leave that for another day, for now.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `partition`, there is still a small step to do.

Take care, you need to *be sure `partition` splits the input in smaller sets all the time*.  In other word, `partition` not to return some empty set.  The pivot can go in any of the sets and use this fact to check that you do not return an empty set, in case your comparison operator does not really decrease the size of the input. This is why I inserted the equality operator -- to be able to check if I insert the pivot in the first returned set or in the second one.

```
(define (partition pivot lst ret)
  ((lambda (s)
     (s s lst
        (lambda (a b p*)
          (if (and (null? a) (null? b))
              (ret (list pivot) (cdr p*))
              (if (null? a)
                  (ret p* b)
                  (if (null? b)
                      (ret a p*)
                      (if (< (car b) pivot)
                          (ret a (append p* b))
                          (if (< (car a) pivot)
                              (ret (append a p*) b)
                              (error "never here")))))))))
   (lambda (s l* c)
     (if (null? l*)
         (c '() '() '())
         (let ((x (car l*)))
           (s s (cdr l*)
              (lambda (a b p*)
                (if (= x pivot)
                    (c a b (cons pivot p*))
                    (if (< x pivot)
                        (c (cons x a) b p*)
                        (c a (cons x b) p*))))))))))

    
(define choose-pivot car)
```

In a real implementation, you will all the time use vectors and this is why the `append` will not be present, as, sorting on the place, at the end of `partition`, both sides will be sorted relatively one to the other.  Here, we need to reassemble the 2 sides using `append`:

```
(define (quicksort lst)
  (if (null? lst) '()
      (if (null? (cdr lst))
          lst
          (let* ((pivot (choose-pivot lst)))
            (partition pivot lst
                       (lambda (p< p>)
                         (append
                           (quicksort p<)
                           (quicksort p>))))))))
```

A test:

```
1 ]=> (quicksort '(1 3 5 7 9 8 6 4 2))
;Value: (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

1 ]=> (quicksort '(1 9 3 8 5 7 7 6 9 5 8 4 6 3 4 2 2 1))
;Value: (1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9)
```

I used as pivot the first element of the input to split, but you can redefine the `choose-pivot` to select other element.

In practice, this algorithm is used in combination with other sorts -- when the input has fewer than 4-8 elements, the `quicksort` is not recurred any more, but other sorting is used for the lowest cases of recurrence relation.

I used directly `<` in the code -- you can insert it as a parameter in case you prefer a more generic procedure...  In any case, the operator that you use needs to simulate the *equality* and *different of* in the same time.

***UPDATE***  I have updated the `partition`, such that to consider duplicated elements.  In my first version, it ignored duplicated elements.

Comment: That's more a merge sort than a quick sort (which, to be fair, is more appropriate for sorting lists anyways; save quicksort for vectors)

Comment: @Shawn Oh, you are right :).  I had forgotten it.  Thank you!  As a prototype and not for a real implementation, just to express the algorithm, it does not matter if you use lists.

Comment: there's no such problem with the code in the Q as it splits off the car as the pivot, and partitions the cdr.

Comment: in your `partition`'s top continuation the `(< (car b) pivot)` case can never hold as all elements in `b` are greater than `pivot` by construction. also, if the input list to `partition` is empty, `(ret (list pivot) (cdr p*))` will cause an error since `p*` will also be empty. Yes, your `qicksort` will never make such a call, but a user might, since `partition` is globally available. another thing is, you insist on building two lists for the `ret` to use, but it's much better to have it handle the three lists as they are, so the top continuation becomes just `(lambda (a b p*) (ret a p* b))`...

Comment: ... then in `quicksort` the call becomes `(partition pivot lst (lambda (p< p= p>) (append (quicksort p<) (append p= (quicksort p>)))))`.

Comment: and it's not merge sort, since `append` is not `merge`. it is actually [a "deforested" tree sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11355621/849891), i.e. tree sort done without building the actual binary tree. (cc @Shawn).

Comment: @WillNess  @Shawn was right.  Before me to update, I had used a merge-function instead of `append`, as I had forgotten and wrote without checking the algorithm.

Comment: Right, hadn't looked at the history. Still, even with merge it's still a tree sort because of the value-based partition, whereas in mergesort the partition is position-based. (And merge works hard but still just appends them, in the end).

Comment: (I meant, in your first version)